# Can I place a Rokit 5 G4 studio monitor on its side (horizontally) and get just as good of a sound?

Tags: home-studio, studio-monitors

*Rokit G4s* come in various sizes.  The manual mentioned only the large Rokit *10-3* on its side but the others aren't mentioned.

This could be because the *10-3* is the only one that supports it.  The writers didn't bother to write that the others were vertical only.

Or it could be because the *10-3* needs extra work to do it.  And the manual didn't think it needed to mention that all could be placed horizontally.  (The *10-3* has 3 cones, while the others have 2, and it needs to be unscrewed and re-arranged to use it on its side.)

General musician knowledge it to NOT use Rokits on their sides, but I'd like a direct opinion or two.

Answer (score -1):

When the speaker is upright the highs and bass are aligned and so reach the listener at the same time. Placing the speaker on its side means the bass and highs are different distances from the listener therefore reaching the listener out of sync. Over short distances the time difference would be marginal but i'd probably advise to use in the vertical alignment.